# Help identify Mega Bloks pieces - giant blue hands, blue and white striped arms and feet, boards/snowshoes

Tags: part-identification, clone-brands

I’ve been sorting through my 19 year old sons Lego and found a few Mega Bloks pieces I can’t identify. Any idea what set these blue and white pieces could be a part of?

[image: Mega Bloks boards][image: Mega Bloks robotic]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The blue boards are from the same Mega Bloks set

[image]

Comment: ooh, clever! i didn't quite see that when looking at the front but i was suspecting the same.

Answer (score 6):

The robot could be this one:

[image]

But I don't know about those boards. Mega Bloks makes minifig-size boards though.