# Can you help identify these bionicles?

Tags: set-identification, bionicle

My elderly father lied to me. He told me I was his favorite child. Later in life he is now asking me to identify his metric ton of Bionicles pieces. He isn’t in the best health so he can’t do it himself, and I’m not the smart one. So I am here with hopes you can help give me some direction so that I can assemble these guys for him.
I don’t know if they’re complete, so I can’t help him sell them until I solve these puzzles.
Thanks in advance.

https://photos.app.goo.gl/1CPqxMZn27NNqny56

Comment: And help me learn how to post all of the photos I took for this post.  Post editing tells me my iPhone photo is too large.

Comment: iPhone photos will be multiple-megapixels with high color information. The maximum photo size for StackExchange is 2MB. You can edit your photos on your phone or a PC and shrink them to 20-25% of the original size and then save as a low-quality JPG, those should upload fine. Edit: looks like you can upload directly using the StackExchange mobile app [source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220342/image-upload-from-photo-gallery)

Comment: I editted the post to add a link to the photos!  Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

I've had a look at the linked photographs and... wow, that's a lot of stuff.

If you plan on reconstructing the sets, remember that you can [search for instructions](https://www.lego.com/en-us/service/buildinginstructions) given a set number.

---

[image: three disassembled bionicles standing up]

From he above picture I can identify:

- [7156-1 "Corroder"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=7156-1) (which is *not* bionicle but rather Hero Factory) (searched for lime bionicle legs)
- [8696-1 "Bitil"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=8696-1) (searched for yellow bionicle legs with 3 technic holes)
- [8695-1 "Gorast"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=8695-1) (just by combing through list of bionicle sets)

---

[image: disassembled dark green bioncle]

- [8622-1 "Nidhiki"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=8622-1) (dark green 7+3 liftarm)

---

[image: disassembled red+gold bionicle]

- [8727-1 "Inika Toa Jaller
  "](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=8727-1) (pearl gold bionicle chest)

---

[image: disassembled black+tan bionicle]

- [8983-1 "Vorox
  "](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=8983-1) (tan bionicle leg)

---

[image: maybe three disassembled figures and lots of spare parts]

- Bits of [8533-1 "Gali"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=8533-1) (medium blue bionicle parts)
- A Mega Blocks blue&white robot at the bottom right, most probably [the "ice" "transformer blok bot" from this other question](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/15953). Note the "mega blocks" markings in the center of groups of four studs.
- Yellow parts possible part of aforementioned [8696-1 "Bitil"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=8696-1)
- Lots of unknown parts

---

[image: disassembled bionicle legs]

- Green technic connector with two ball sockets, from [one of four possible sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=50898&colorID=34&in=A). I'm guessing [8914-1 "Toa Mahri Hahli
  "](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=8914-1) based on the attached dark blue parts, and a mask from a different photograph.
- Clawed feet from aforementioned [8983-1 "Vorox
  "](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=8983-1), even though the colour doesn't seem to match in the photograph (due to white balance, perhaps?)

---

[image: several disassembled bionicles and spare parts]

- [8979-1 "Malum"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=8979-1) (red & "marbled bright orange" chest, bottom center)
- [8567-1 "Lewa Nuva"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=8567-1) (lime legs, bottom left)
- [8570-1 "Gali Nuva"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=8570-1) (medium blue legs, between top right and middle right)
- [8591-1 "Vorak"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=8591-1) (spikes on black [bionicle back cover with groove](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=44140), just above center)
- [8589-1 "Lerahk"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=8589-1) (green back cover with groove; note spikes through groove are switched)
- [8590-1 "Guurahk"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=8590-1) (blue back cover with groove; note spikes through groove back are switched)
- [8592-1 "Turahk"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=8592-1) (back blades with holes, inserted in the blue back cover)
- Lots of other unidentified parts

---

[image: Lots of disassembled bionicles]

- [8568-1 "Potahu Nuva"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=8568-1) (tan legs connected to brown parts, above revolver)
- [8911-1 "Toa Mahi Jaller"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=8911-1) (6-shot revolver-like part, connected to red&orange parts; also mask appears in later photograph)
- Transparent wings with hexagon-like pattern from aforementioned [8695-1 "Gorast"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=8695-1) (in the pile at the very top)
- Lots of other unidentified parts

---

[image: black spider-like bionicle]

- [8561-1 "Nuhvok"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=8561-1) (via trans-neon-green teeth)

---

[image: disassembled orange bionicle with disk launcher]

- [8615-1 "Vahki Bordakh"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=8615-1) (disk launcher with trans-orange head connector)

---

[image: four projectile launchers and a base for a six-legged something]

- [8685-1 "Phantoka"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=8685-1) (black & grey projectile launcher paired with a mask from a later photograph)
- [8913-1 "Toa Mahri Nuparu"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=8913-1) (revolver projectile launcher and mask from later photograph)
- [8925-1 "Barraki Deepsea Patrol"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=8925-1) (6x11 assembly at top, with 6x10 + 1x6 black plates, consistent with black whip from later photograph)
- Aforementioned [8914-1 "Toa Mahri Hahli
  "](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=8914-1) (remaining revolver projectile launcher)
- Other unidentified parts

---

[image: white, black and blue bionicle heads]

- [8747-1 "Visorak Suukorak"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=8747-1)
- The black head [appears in two sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=57550pb01&in=S). I'm gonna take a wild guess and say [8919-1 "Mantax"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=8919-1)
- [8743-1 "Visorak Boggarak"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=8743-1)

---

That's all I can identify for now. You might want to rebuild all known sets, and come back here later with the remaining parts for a second round.

Comment: Wow!  Thank you SO much. This is incredibly helpful!

Comment: The blue and white Mega Bloks parts are from [this set](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/15953/help-identify-mega-bloks-pieces-giant-blue-hands-blue-and-white-striped-arms)

Comment: @Syberion I'll edit the answer to add that info, thanks!